# Change destination build directory in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I'm new to Visual Studio. I have imported a Visual Studio project made of several sub-projects. I can build all of them, but I don't know where the IDE put the executables files once built.

How can I get/set the destination directory of a project from Visual Studio?

I'm using [Visual C++ 2010 Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#Visual_C.2B.2B_Express).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default output directory is :

```
$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\
```

So by default, output binaries will be created in:

```
Path\To\Your\Solution\[Configuration]\.
```

Configuration can be something like "Debug" or "Release".

Depending on your project settings, these directories can vary. You can see/change those settings in :

Menu Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General -> Output Directory

Comment: thanks for the answer..I found that dir. But I don't see any .exe file there even I built the project successfully. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you able to actually run the executable ? If so, you should see the path to your .exe file in the Output console. May be it's not a "Application (.exe)" project type (you can see this in the "Configuration Properties" pane along with the "Output Directory")

Comment: well, I checked it. It should generate an .exe file. Build process succeded, but no executable files are put inside the target directory.