# Qt Visual Studio Addin shadow build

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, qt

I have a Qt project (`.pro`) and I can successfully open it in VS2010 using Qt Visual Studio Addin. It works but it makes a huge mess in my source directory. Is it possible to configure Addin, so it will generate VS project files (`*.sln`, `*.sdf`, `*.vcxproj`, `*.vcxproj.filters`, `*.vcxproj.user`, `debug/*`, `release/*`) in separate "build" directory?

Comment: You are not using VCS to clean up easily?

Comment: Version Control System.

Comment: I don't want my VCS to delete *.sln, *.sdf, *.vcxproj... maybe  debug/*, release/*

Comment: That is fine, that is what .gitignore is for. ;-)

Comment: thanks for the workaround. Anyway ignoring the problem is not solution for me :D

Comment: I would not call it a workaround or ignoring the problem, but as you feel. Why cannot you just do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959001/change-destination-build-directory-in-visual-studio) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5554269/2682142)?

Comment: .gitignore is completely ignoring the stated problem. The files may not be in VCS but they're still polluting my workspace. Shadow build is the One True Way™. I want to be able to have multiple build trees targeting the same source tree but using different builds of Qt, for example.

Answer (score 0):

It is stupid simple with `Qt5`.

```
mkdir build
cd build
qmake -r -tp vc ../my-project/MyProject.pro
```

Then you will get the generated `sln` files and the same directory structure as the source directory.